# How to extract values from columns in CSV using a loop and use them in email body using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

[This is the information that needs to be mailed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7W6p.png)

I am trying to send the values of "id" and "desc" to the emails that in column B. I used a for loop to go through the email list and send emails, however, I am unable to attach the values of "id" and "desc" in my email.

Plus, I want the "assigned to" column to be filled with the email id that the "id" is sent to.

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client

e = pd.read_csv('combo.csv')
emails = e['Emails'].values
ticket_number = e['id'].values
desc_value = e['desc'].values
for i in emails, ticket_number, desc_value:
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    message = 'Hello the ticket number {ticket_number} with the Description {desc_value} has been assigned to you.'
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = i
    mail.Subject = 'This is a test'
    mail.HTMLBody = message
    mail.Send()
```

Can someone guide me as to how 
1. Use the values to send the email.
2. Add the emails in the "assigned to" column once the email is sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client


def send_mail(email, ticket_number, desc_value):
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    message = f'Hello the ticket number {ticket_number} with the Description {desc_value} has been assigned to you.'
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = email
    mail.Subject = 'This is a test'
    mail.HTMLBody = message
    mail.Send()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    df = pd.read_csv('combo.csv')
    df.apply(lambda row: send_mail(row['Emails'], row['id'], row['desc']), axis=1)
```

or just make changes in your code:

```
import pandas as pd
import win32com.client

e = pd.read_csv('combo.csv')
emails = e['Emails'].values
ticket_number = e['id'].values
desc_value = e['desc'].values
for i in range(len(emails)):
    outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
    message = f'Hello the ticket number {ticket_number[i]} with the Description {desc_value[i]} has been assigned to you.'
    mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    mail.To = emails[i]
    mail.Subject = 'This is a test'
    mail.HTMLBody = message
    mail.Send()
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much, the above worked for me. However, I do have one more request, once a mail is sent, how do I assign the email id to the "assigned to" column in the combo.csv file? (Check out the image at the beginning of the post to get an idea of how the CSV looks)